# Передача таблиц из MSSQL в MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

В общем, на `MS SQL` есть прилинкованный `MYSQL` и я могу обращаться к нему через `OPENQUERY`, что бы получить небольшой кусок данных, с которым хочу что-то сделать на стороне MS SQL(не важно).

Однако, проблема в том, что запросы вида:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY()

INNER JOIN
```

Коряво работают, так как сначала все данные выкачиваются в `MS SQL`, а уж потом выполняется JOIN, что не эффективно из-за большого объема данных.

Я могу как-то из `MS SQL` запросом передать таблицу с необходимыми данными(Список ID например) на `MYSQL`, что бы внутри `OPENQUERY` выполнить фильтрацию по этой таблице и наружу получить быстро только необходимые данные?

Подобное, без проблем работает между линкованными `MSSQL` серверами.

Да, есть утилита `Import/Export`, но это лишние телодвижения..., а хотелось бы 1 скриптом решить задачу.

Comment: *таблицу с необходимыми данными(Список ID например)* Формально можно интегрировать эти данные в текст запроса (скажем, в виде CTE). Но я бы попробовал сперва залить через OPENQUERY данные для отбора во (временную) таблицу, а потом во втором OPENQUERY использовать её в тексте запроса.

Comment: @Akina Хм... Мне казалось, что он Read Only. А пример можете привести, как залить данные из MS SQL через OPENQUERY?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, пример Б.

Comment: @Akina Хм... Работает. А он пакетно заливает или по 1 записи?  . А можно через OPEN QUERY создать таблицу на стороне MY SQL из MS SQL?

Comment: *можно через OPEN QUERY создать таблицу на стороне MY SQL из MS SQL?* Попробуй... мне не на чем.

Comment: @Akina Вот такая хрень сработала EXEC ('CREATE TABLE `Test`.`Test2` (`idTest` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`idTest`));') At Test

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что `OPENQUERY()` поддерживает операции модификации данные и я просто смог сделать запрос вида(Спасибо @Akina за наводку):

```
INSERT OPENQUERY (MYSQL, 'SELECT name FROM table')  
SELECT Name from Table
```

Что бы залить данные на MYSQL и уже дальше, через

```
EXEC (QUERY) AT MYSQL
```

Выполняю запросы из MSSQL на стороне MYSQL, но нужно еще RPC включить в настройках линковки.